# INSTR in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using this function to filter data by program codes entered, if nothing is entered return all?

Can any one please explain this Crystal function, and how Crystal works with it? Mainly the last statement.

Here is some information that might be useful.

```
{?Program} ==> Parameter to accept different programs codes in the following form
303&410&110
{Command.program_code} ==> Field were program code is stored

if ({?Program} = "")
then true
else
    (INSTR("&" &  {?Program} &"&", "&"& {Command.program_code} & "&")>0)
```

Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you look up the function in the documentation instead of waiting for someone to explain it to you?

Comment: I know the function looks for an existence of the second parameter string in the first and returns the location where the pattern starts matching, I just have problems putting these in my mind, and I thought if I read an explanation from some one else that will help me understand better. Thank you anyways for your support